# Windows Phone 7 Convert MediaLibrary Picture to imagesource

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I convert a Image stream from the Picture to an imagesource?

Im using this

```
  MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
                foreach (Picture Alb in library.Pictures)
                {
                    Z.ImageSource = Alb.GetImage();                        
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to turn the stream into an image to use it.

I'm not sure what `z` is in your example.
So, assuming you just wanted one image:

```
<Image x:Name="z" />
```

You could do:

```
var library = new MediaLibrary();

var picStream = library.Pictures.First();

var img = new BitmapImage();
img.SetSource(picStream.GetImage());

z.Source = img;
```

Comment: Z was just a test image I was using, many thanks for your help. Sp

Comment: @Steven If, in your example, `Z` was an image, you were trying to repeatedly set it's source to be each image in the library

Comment: I was debuging the code and removed a bunch of lines, thanks for your help :)